# apache - if 404 and image redirect to another server

Tags: php, apache, redirect

I encountered a need to perform what's in the title - check if it's a 404 error, and a media request (basically jpg,png,gif,bmp,mp3,pdf and some more) - redirect the request to another server.

The reason is that the web application is vulnerable open source one, and I currently can't fix upload related issues hence blocking all uploads via php.ini (file_uploads=off). I copied the application to another htpwd protected server which only allows access with no password to the above media type.

I didn't manage to correctly condition the code to check - 
If 404 error (so it's not already on the server) + a media request (above extensions) the go to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/$1.

Would appreciate assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your specific needs, I have written a simple function. It might help you. Check and make the needed adjustments where necessary:

Function:

```
<?php
    function checkMedia($request) {
        $info = pathinfo($request);
        $extension = @$info['extension'];
        $valid_formats = array("pdf", "png", "jpeg"); // add all media extensions you want to check against
        foreach($valid_formats AS $format) {
            if($format == $extension) {
                $headers = @get_headers($request);
                if($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found') {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

And then use the function like this to check for the request type and file existence:

```
<?php
    $request = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";        
    $media = checkMedia($request);
    if($media) {
        // it is a media request and file does not exist
        // header("Location: somepath.php");
    } else {
        // it is not a media request or the file exists on server
    }
?>
```

**Explanation:** I have used three inbuilt functions of PHP to write this new function.

1. **`pathinfo()`:** I have used this function to extract the extension information from the request URL if any
2. **`get_headers()`:** [This function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) provides us the information about [HTTP response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html) the target server sends us for a request. I have used this to check either it sends us a `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found` header or not for our request.
3. Lastly, I have suggested you to use the `header()` function to redirect somewhere else if it is a media request and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer - I had in mind a simpler apache solution - chaining two condition and then redirecting - would such thing be possible?

Answer (score 0):

you need to re-install a new copy of the apace web server; you must have changed it and it'll take hours to figure out.

back up your current settings. reinstall and apache and try doing it again imho.